# Why is it impossible to declare a type alias to an F# struct tuple?

Tags: f#, valuetuple

It is impossible to define a type alias to a struct tuple in F#. Only with a workaround, it works.

```
let x = struct (1, 2)
> val x : struct (int * int) = struct (1, 2)

let y : struct (int * int) = struct (4, 5) // explicit type
> val y : struct (int * int) = struct (4, 5)

type S = struct (int * int) // straight definition
> error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '(' in member definition

type S = ValueTuple<int, int> // workaround
> [<Struct>]
  type S = struct (int * int)
```

Is the error for "type S = struct (int * int)" a compiler bug?

Comment: no this is a language feature. you can however try `type S = int * int` then `let s = S(1,2)`.

Comment: thx but you did not understand the question.

Comment: I would say `ValueTuple<int, int>` is the straight definition but the friendlier name `struct (int * int)` should work. Best to file in dotnet/fsharp .

Comment: will do, thx for your confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried to file a bug and found the answer here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7014

parenthesis around the type are required:

```
type Alias = (struct(int * int))
```